# how do I execute deferred functions in TestMain for a test suite?

Tags: go

I've updated the question to avoid being accused of posting an XY question.

Previously the question was:

> how can I tell when runtime.Goexit has been called on the main goroutine?

I'm trying to write a method that finishes all deferred functions on the main goroutine by calling `runtime.Goexit()` and then calls `os.Exit()` from a goroutine a spawned before calling this exit method.  The problem I have is that I don't know when `runtime.Goexit()` has completed.  Is there any way I can know when the main goroutine has finished?

UPDATED: Let me elaborate on my use case.  Consider this pattern for `TestMain`:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    db.Create()
    defer db.Drop()
    os.Exit(m.Run())
}
```

In this case, the database is never dropped because os.Exit stops the program.  My goal was to come up with an alternate 
exit function that executes all the deferred functions in `TestMain`.  Now, I could move everything into another
function like this:

```
func realTestMain(m *testing.M) int {
    db.Create()
    defer db.Drop()
    return m.Run()
}

func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    os.Exit(realTestMain(m))
}
```

However, this pattern would have to be enforced across our test suite and is ugly and difficult to remember.  I was exploring
whether I could have a helper that makes it possible to write my setup/teardown as follows:

```
func TestMain(m *testing.M) {
    db.Create()
    defer db.Drop()
    helpers.SafeExit(m.Run())
}
```

With a helper like this, I could write a simple check to ensure that os.Exit never appears in our test suites.

Comment: This is an XY Problem. Don't focus on `runtime.Goexit` (your imagined solution), instead focus on the actual problem to be solved.

Answer (score 4):

If you want to ensure coordinated cleanup *DON'T* use `runtime.Goexit`. There is no reliable/deterministic mechanism to hook onto this type of exit method.

Instead use [context.Context](https://golang.org/pkg/context/) and pass it to your relevant go-routines. You can explicitly cancel a Context and the go-routines can monitor it's state for such an event and do their cleanup.

If there is critical tasks that need executing prior to mains exit, you can employ a [sync.WaitGroup](https://golang.org/pkg/sync/#WaitGroup). Adding to the wait group for each go-routine. And performing `Done()` on the WaitGroup as each go-routine completes. The main go-routine can finally  `Wait()` on the WaitGroup and the program will exit, safe in the knowledge all cleanup tasks having been completed.

---

**Example:**

```
func main() {
    mainCtx, cancelFn := context.WithCancel(context.Background())
    var wg sync.WaitGroup

    wg.Add(1)
    go func() { taskA(mainCtx, &wg) }()
    wg.Add(1)
    go func() { manager(mainCtx, &wg, cancelFn) }()

    wg.Wait() // waiting for manager/task(s)
}


func taskA(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup) {
    defer func() {
        log.Println("defer(): taskA DONE!")
        wg.Done() // must be called last
    }()

    t := time.NewTicker(300 * time.Millisecond)

    for {
        select {
        case <-t.C:
            log.Println("taskA is working:", time.Now())
        case <-ctx.Done(): // are we done?
            log.Println("taskA was canceled. Reason:", ctx.Err())
            return
        }
    }
}

func manager(ctx context.Context, wg *sync.WaitGroup, cancelFn func()) {
    defer func() {
        log.Println("defer(): Manager DONE!")
        wg.Done() // must be called last
    }()

    time.Sleep(time.Second) // give worker(s) some time to work...

    cancelFn() // time to wrap up worker(s)!
}
```

---

Working [playground version](https://play.golang.org/p/bQ6UzI3A-Ln).

Answer (score 1):

> Is there any way I can know when the main goroutine has finished?

Yes: When your program has stopped.

Once the main goroutine stops your program terminates including any other goroutine. So you will have to redesign as nothing ever executes after the main goroutine exits.

Comment: Although a bit snarky, this is the only technically correct answer to the XY problem posed by the OP.  For an answer to the actual situation of the OP, @colminator's answer is great.

Answer (score -2):

Here's a solution I was able to come up with using a finalizer on a variable on the main goroutine and then triggering garbage collection:

```
package main

import (
  "fmt"
  "os"
  "runtime"
  "time"
)

type toBeCollected struct {
  dummy bool // need to have a non-empty struct
}

func main() {
  collectMe := new(toBeCollected)
  runtime.SetFinalizer(collectMe, func(*toBeCollected) {
    fmt.Println("now I'm really done")
    os.Exit(0)
  })
  go func() {
    for range time.NewTicker(time.Millisecond).C {
      runtime.GC()
    }
  }()
  runtime.Goexit()
}
```

Curiously while I can run it locally, it doesn't work on go playground (see  https://play.golang.org/p/bwf7fMu2w76).

Comment: Don't use finalizers. They're unreliable. They're not guaranteed to run when you expect. In your case, your finalizer _could_ run before your `go func()` is executed, becuase the runtime can detect that `collectMe` is not used in the rest of the function, so it may do a pre-cleanup. If GC is ever delayed, it could also be cleaned up after you expect (this case may not matter since you're existing the program, but in any other case, it could).

Comment: @flI was wondering about this.  If I reference collectMe after I call `runtime.Goexit()` can I be guaranteed that the object won't be cleaned up before my finalizer?

Comment: No. The compiler and runtime are very smart about disregarding things after early exits. Even if it works in a current version of Go, it's likely to be optimized away in upcoming versions. Simply don't use finalizers for side-effects. Use them only for finalization.